# React dApp button that sends crypto to user's wallet

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transactions

I'm trying to create a little game where the the user connects his wallet and then when they press a button, it'll send a certain amount of my custom spl token. Don't have a lot of experience in react native or when it comes to writing smart contracts. would mean alot if someone could help me out.